# no apps folder in itunes 11.0.1

Tags: iphone, itunes

I developed ipad app. Now I want to test it in my ipad. I already jailbroke ipad. Now I have to drag that app to itunes inside app folder. But unfortunately, I do not have apps folder in my itunes. How can I make move it to my ipad to test app?

Answer (score 1):

I found its solution. I needed to go to the iTunes preferences. Make sure that "apps" is checkmarked".

Answer (score 0):

There's Apps section in iTunes 11.0.1. Check the below image :

[image]

This is how it'll look.

[image]

Comment: For me there is `Music, Movies, TV Shows, Books and Home Sharing`. There is no apps in there.

Comment: If you drag your .ipa files in iTunes window. What happens?

Comment: What is .ipa? Could you tell me about that? when I drag myapp.app to itunes then it moves back to its original directory and does not show up in itunes.

Comment: .ipa is a distributed build file of your application. I think you should update your iTunes

Comment: I do not have .ipa file. When I build my app in xcode, it generate .app file inside product folder. I am trying to test this file in my ipad.

Comment: I updated my itunes to latest version i.e. 11.0.2 but still no apps folder.